# How to mount php.ini file in a bitnami/moodle container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, moodle, bitnami

I need to edit the `php.ini` file in a bitnami/moodle container. As I couldn't manage to install a text editor inside the container, I tried to mount the file to my host. The relevant file in the container is `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`.

Below is an exerpt from the `docker-compose.yml` file I use. I tried to add a third volume in multiple ways, but I can't start the container when I mount anything from `/opt`. Depending on the path I specify, I keep getting one of two error messages: `cp: cannot stat '/opt/bitnami/php/etc/common.conf.disabled': No such file or directory` (when trying to mount `/opt/bitnami/php/etc`) or the one below (when trying to mount `/opt`):

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/opt/bitnami/scripts/moodle/entrypoint.sh": stat /opt/bitnami/scripts/moodle/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

```
services:
  moodle:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    container_name: foo_moodle
    depends_on:
      - moodle_db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_TYPE=pgsql
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=moodle_db
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=5432
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=${MOODLE_DB_USER}
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=${MOODLE_DB_NAME}
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${MOODLE_DB_PASS}
      - MOODLE_SITE_NAME=${MOODLE_SITE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./moodle/mount_moodle:/bitnami/moodle
      - ./moodle/mount_moodle_data:/bitnami/moodledata
```

How can I mount `php.ini`?

Comment: I'd still like to understand what is wrong with my approach, but could solve my problem using an environment variable. There are quite a few options to configure PHP: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/moodle

Answer (score 0):

I would modify a single configuration file like this in the Dockerfile and not using a volume mount. The mount would replace a entire directory so probably necessitate having divergent copies of many files. In the Bitnami Moodle image I'm looking at, php.ini is in /opt/bitnami/php/etc and there are a number of other files (and directories) in there, all of which you'd be replacing with your volume. Then, if you go to update the base image you're using, you might have to check against all these files for changes.

To add a local php.ini in a Dockerfile it'd look like this:

```dockerfile
FROM bitnami/moodle
COPY php.ini /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
```

where php.ini is a local file with your changes.

> As I couldn't manage to install a text editor inside the container

I ran into trouble adding packages to containers a lot too because the best practices for building an image usually involve deleting all the package source lists to minimize the size of the image. So your typical `apt-get install` commands don't work, you'd need to add a bunch of sources first, then update, then install. Just FYI, the Bitnami containers usually have an `install_packages` command so you should be able to `install_packages vim`. You could also add a text editor in the Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM bitnami/moodle
COPY php.ini /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```